# A word conveying the fact for a work to belong to an artistic category

Tags: word-request

If one intends to determine whether or not a work belongs to an artistic category, what word could replace "XXX" in the following sentence?

"Assessing the XXX of this work to this category is a hard task."

"Belonging" sounds a bit awkward to my ears. Is it a suitable option?

Comment: Maybe "fit" or "fitness".

Comment: Or, slightly rewording, Assessing whether this work fits in this category is difficult.